# Matching multiline javascript import using vim regex

Tags: javascript, regex, vim, neovim

I have these imports in js file

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import {
  fullName,
} from '../../../common/helpers/users';
```

I'm trying to match only the second import. I tried using this search

`/^import\s{\_.*}\sfrom\s'\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/common\/helpers\/users';$`

and also this one using `\v`

`/\v^import\s\{\_.*\}\sfrom\s'\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/common\/helpers\/users';`

But both of these regex patterns matches both imports (basically everything). How can i match only the second one?

```
import {
  fullName,
} from '../../../common/helpers/users'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding a newline to your first expression will match the second import statement but not the first.

```
^import\s{\n\_.*}\sfrom\s'\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/common\/helpers\/users';$
```

If you wanted to allow trailing spaces before the newline, you could add that also.

```
^import\s{\s*\n\_.*}\sfrom\s'\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/common\/helpers\/users';$
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add a `\n` after `{`:

```
/^import\s{\n\_.*}\sfrom\s'\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/common\/helpers\/users';$
```

**Explanation**

`\_.` matches any single character or **end-of-line**, so `import` statement with or without linefeed after `{` will both be matched.

By adding a `\n` after `{`, vim will match only the second type of `import` statement.

Comment: I was hoping i could have a pattern that will match both single and multiline imports
`import { fullName } from 'file'